# Python Tkinter - Is is possible to link the geometry manager of two separate grids

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like the column widths of two separate grids to have equal widths, that same way that they would if they were all in the same grid. The two frames/grids will be packed on top of each other in a separate parent widget.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Label


class Main:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

        myRow1 = MyRow(self.master, [1, 2, 3], bg='grey55')
        myRow2 = MyRow(self.master, ['one', 'two', 'three'], bg='grey55')

        myRow1.pack(side='top')
        myRow2.pack(side='top')

class MyRow(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, values, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)

        Label(self, text=values[0]).grid(row=0, column=0, padx=1, pady=1)
        Label(self, text=values[1]).grid(row=0, column=1, padx=1, pady=1)
        Label(self, text=values[2]).grid(row=0, column=2, padx=1, pady=1)

mw = Tk()

main = Main(mw)

mw.mainloop()
```

In this example I would want the column widths from `myRow1` to match the column widths from `myRow2`

I could have all the Labels be packed in self.master but I would have to define the row when i create the object, this is what I did to get the second image below.

```
class MyRow(Frame):
    myrow = -1
    def __init__(self, master, values, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
        MyRow.myrow += 1

        Label(self.master, text=values[0]).grid(row=MyRow.myrow, column=0, padx=1, pady=1)
        Label(self.master, text=values[1]).grid(row=MyRow.myrow, column=1, padx=1, pady=1)
        Label(self.master, text=values[2]).grid(row=MyRow.myrow, column=2, padx=1, pady=1)
```

Even though this is a valid workaround I'm curious if its possible to link two grids to have equal column widths and/or row heights. This would come in handy if you have a scrollable frame and want a header row that is always visible. Currently the only way I can get two grids to line up is to manually define the widths.

The UI currently look like this:
[image: Currently looks like this.]

I would like it to look like this:
[image: I would like it to look like this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is is possible to link the geometry manager of two separate grids

No, it is not. You have to manually force the columns to have identical widths.